# Xcode 4: Navigate through source code (back/forth) like in eclipse

Tags: xcode

In Eclipse it is possible to hold the CTRL key, click on a type/definition/variable/... and a new editor with the definition of the type will be shown. This works also greatly in Xcode 4.

In addition to this, in eclipse, you can go back to the original editor by pressing [ALT]+[LEFT ARROW] and forth again by pressing [ALT]+[RIGHT ARROW].

How can I use this back/forth functionality in Xcode?

(please no links to PDFs showing all hotkeys, I cannot find what I am searching for there :))

Comment: I don't know about a key command, but the editors have back buttons in the upper left corner.

Comment: Ah, this is already great! Althought I am still a big fan of fast shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

You can go back and forth through the following:

1. Menu Bar: Navigate > Go Back / Go Forward
2. Keyboard Shortcuts: Control-Command-Left (Go Back) / Control-Command-Right (Go Forward)
3. Lion, using trackpad (not sure if working on Snow Leopard): continue scrolling towards the left/right; eventually this will become Go Back / Go Forward
4. Buttons on the image:
   [image: Xcode 4 Back & Forward]